# azure move validation error

Tags: validation, azure

I am trying to move Azure resources to a different subscription/resource group within my account. Was able to move most resources but some gave error:

> VALIDATION ERROR / ERROR TYPE Resource move validation failed. Please
>   see details. Diagnostic information: timestamp '20161130T144724Z',
>   subscription id '290b5843-765a-4b08-98a6-xxxxxxxxxx', tracking id
>   'd8616912-dfda-4bd0-853e-88e438a37ca5', request correlation id
>   '65f88afd-5e9f-47ba-ab17-a96b548d7e4b'. (Code:
>   ResourceMoveProviderValidationFailed)

The move resources request does not contain all the dependent resources. Please check error details for missing resource ids. 
(`Code: MissingMoveDependentResources`)

I have tried looking through diagnostic logs and used `Get-AzureRMLog` command but have not been able to get information on the validation error or the dependent resource. Can someone tell me which resources are missing or how to get log details.

Comment: Please update your question and include what kind of resources were failed to move. From what I know, not all resource types support moving from one resource group to another.

Comment: figured this out - had storage account in different resource group, move it to same RG as the VM and after move the entire RG to new subscription/RG